# Banach Space Isomorphism vs Hilbert Space Isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Two Banach spaces $X,Y$ are isomorphic if there is a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ that is also a bicontinuous bijection.  In other words, Banach Space Isomorphism = Linear Homeomorphism.  If $T$ in addition perserves norm, then it is an "isometric isomorphism."

Two Hilbert Sapces $H_1, H_2$ are isomorphic if there is an *onto* linear operator $U:H_1\to H_2$ such that $(Ux,Uy)_{H_1}=(x,y)_{H_2}$ for all $x,y\in H_1$.  In other words, Hilbert Space Isomorphism = Linear Surjective Isometry.  (I recognise that this is an equivalence relation, but what is the reason for not requiring injectivity?)

I am wondering why the definitions have been chosen as such.  For example, consider $S:L^2\to L^2$ such that $[Sf](x)=2f(x)$.  It is an isomorphism in the Banach sense but not an isomorphism in the Hilbert sense, because it does not preserve the metric.  This is a little confusing.

Naively, I say we can just use the words "linear homeomorphism" and "isometric linear homeomorphism" for Banach isomorphism and Banach isometric isomorphism; and then there won't be any confusion.

Lastly, is there a reason we want to think of Hilbert space not up to equivalent inner products, but think of Banach spaces up to equivalent norms?

This link may be relevant to the reader, though I became more confused after reading it. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80567/what-is-an-isomorphism-of-banach-spaces

Thanks!

Comment: Injectivity *is* required, because isometries are always injective.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! @DanielHast